# Book suggestion for a first course in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I am self learner currently learning mathematics. I am studying elementary real analysis from Stephen Abbhot's book and i have some experience with proofs also from book "How to prove it". I would like to embark on journey to abstract algebra. I have looked similar suggestions here and came up with two books which are as :

**1. Abstract algebra by Charles Pinter**

**2. A first course in abstract algebra by J.B.Fraleigh**

I would like to know any more books which are available for self study so that i can have a look at them before buying and advice in general to subject.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe look at Algebra : An introduction by Hungerford

Comment: Also Dummit and Foote, Abstract algebra.

Comment: Algebra by Serge Lang.

Comment: @PeterMelech In my honest opinion Algebra by Serge Lang would be pretty difficult for a first course in abstract algebra. I think for a first course, Dummit and Foote is good and is the popular choice among many for good reason.

Comment: Slightly off topic... if you allow online lectures, I'd nominate [Visual Group Theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwTQdOop-nU&list=PLwV-9DG53NDxU337smpTwm6sef4x-SCLv), a series that visually illustrates many concepts along the learning curve.  Great to binge watch for starters.

Comment: Thanks ........

Comment: @FrenzyLi If you click on the course webpage linked in the video, you'll find that these video lectures are based in part on the book [*Visual Group Theory*](https://www.maa.org/press/books/visual-group-theory) by Nathan Carter. So I think your suggestion could be an answer!

Comment: General subject recommendations have been asked to death on the site, pretty much. Abstract algebra is no exception. It appears you were aware of at least some duplicates of this question before asking. Please don't duplicate posts. If you do have some reason for eliminating (the numerous) recommendations given, you should explain why.

Comment: @rschwieb Well, i have posted my current level of understaning and which nooks i am studying right now

Comment: @JessicaJeffery I don’t think that eliminates any of the numerous suggestions I’m alluding to. Almost everyone wants the same thing from introductory books, and usually mention secondary books too.

Answer (score 4):

If you are essentially new to proofs then I recommend Galian’s “Contemporary Abstract Algebra” due to the simplicity of the text. It is full of problems (mostly easy), examples and pictures. I’m also a fan of the biographical notes at the end of each chapter.

If you have a little bit of experience then Dummit and Foote have a wonderful Algebra text (my personal favorite). It is much more in depth than Galian’s text but it is still reasonably easy to follow for the most part (a few difficult sections here and there).

Lang’s book is incredible but is probably too advanced for a first read through. One professor of mine has told me - It is the best way to learn algebra but it is the hardest way to learn algebra.

Artin has an excellent book as well that a few of my friends have enjoyed although I’d say that it is another challenging book and may not be ideal for a first time read through in algebra.

Comment: Lang is just too sloppy with details and with correctness (exercises full of typos don't really make for fun self-learning); it would otherwise be a great text.

Comment: i have looked at Gallian also. thanks